# security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relation on domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2022

I am so sorry to seek your attention for a question of a foolish action. I accidentally renamed the server (Domain controller) when it was already active as domain controller, completely forgetting that the error written in the title came out. Any idea how to fix this, or how to create a new DC without losing all the data? (I would just need to save the users and some RADIUS settings.

Thank you very much and I wish a happy new year to everyone

Signed (The nice guy who doesn't even remember that when you change the name of the DC, it remembers the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never did it, but it seem you can recover your server by using netdom in DSR mode to rename the DC the correct's way.

I hope you remember your DSR password..

Quote from; [How to rename Windows Server 2016 Domain Controller](https://www.kieri.com/how-to-rename-windows-server-2016-domain-controller/)

[image]

A feedback on that procedure; so it seem to be a way.

[image]